# Is there a way of stacking two variables onto a distplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I have two distplots, is there a way of combining them onto a single graph?

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.set_title('Distribution plots of utime')
sns.distplot(transcode_data['utime'], color = 'blue')


ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.set_title('Distribution of umem')
sns.distplot(transcode_data['umem'], color = 'red')
```

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

Comment: Just plot twice on the same `ax`: `sns.distplot(transcode_data['utime'], color = 'blue', ax=ax2)` and `sns.distplot(transcode_data['umem'], color = 'red', ax=ax2)`.  Note that `distplot(...)` has been replaced by `sns.histplot(...., kde=True)` in the latest seaborn version.

Comment: Note that both plots won't combine well, as their x and y ranges differ too much. It's probably clearer leaving them on separate subplots.